# PHP - trying to put a variable value inside a file

Tags: php, html, email

I have a PHP file (mail-mail.php) that send some mails when a form passes him some infos, and works great.

All the mails were once inserted in the main file (mail-mail.php) like this

```
body = <<<BODY
-THE ENTIRE HTML CODE OF THE MAIL-
BODY;
```

File become very huge (mail-mail.php send 3-5 mails everytime that runs) very long (more than 500 lines), and not comfortable if i have to change the mail contents

So i decided to take the entire mail code out and replaced them with some external files with the HTML code of the mail.

```
$body = file_get_contents('./mail/inv.php');
```

Inside the HTML code there is a variable ($name) that in the <<

I tried to load the file separately in this way

```
$body = str_replace("$name", $name, file_get_contents('./mail/inv.php'));
```

or this way

```
$prebody = file_get_contents('./mail/inv.php');
$body = str_replace("$name", $name, $prebody);
```

but still the $prebody (and the $body of course) loads "inv.php" without changing the $name value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the text `$variable` you will need to either use singlequotes, or escape your variable character (`$`)

right now "$name" becomes "" and doesnt replace anything. singlequote strings are NOT parsed for variables.

See also: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$body = str_replace("$name", $name, $prebody);
```

Because you put `$name` in double quotes it is affected by [variable parsing](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) inside strings (i.e. it is replaced with the value of variable `$name`).

The line above is the same as:

```
$body = str_replace($name, $name, $prebody);
```

which means you try to replace the value you have in variable `$name` with itself. Of course, this returns an unchanged copy of `$prebody`.

Put `$name` in single quotes and it will work:

```
$body = str_replace('$name', $name, $prebody);
```